# Determine Los Angeles neighborhoods based on coordinates

Tags: arcmap, coordinates, spatial-join, gis-principle, intersect

I'm new to the GIS world. I've read several sites and previous posts but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I have a data set of ~400k coordinates from Los Angeles and would now like to determine their respective neighborhood.

```
Lat            Lon
-118.4382362   34.2530534   
(...)
```

What would be the best way to determine the coordinates neighborhood?

---

EDIT: I started working with ArcMap and plotted some test coordinates on a shapefile.

[image]

How would I now match the neighborhood names from the shapefile to my coordinate data? When I use the join function, it only counts how many coordinates occur in a specific neighborhood. However, I'd like to know the opposite i.e. the respective neighborhood name per coordinate pair.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our format.  What GIS software are you using?  What data do you have available, and what format are your 400k coordinates?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using QGIS. I received the coordinates through Google Maps' API using R. The coordinates are in CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be, independent of software, to spatially join or intersect your 400k coordinates to a data layer of Los Angeles neighborhoods. This would append the data from the neighborhood layer onto your coordinate layer, or create a new layer of the combined data

Comment: Is there a way you could show me how to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Unsure of how this workflow goes in QGIS, im sure the terminology is the same

Comment: That doesn't really help me yet. Alternatively, I was thinking, would it be possible to get the Zip Codes for my ~400k coordinates. What I have is the Street name and the coordinates. Getting the zip codes would actually be all what I need.

Comment: @Makism: Do you know how to do this in ArcMap?

Comment: Yes, basically what I gave in the answer would be the steps in ArcMap. Either spatially join your points to polygons, or intersect the two